# How to put an image in a drag and drop area(dropify) via jquery- Dynamic dropify

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropify(drag and drop) area in my web site. I need fill the drag and drop area with existing image so users can view old image and can change if they want.
Possibilities
1. Is there any way to generate trigger with old file name. so that dropify JavaScript can detect the event and can handle rest
2. Is there any way to explicitly set image on the dropify area from another JavaScript file.

code:

```
<pre>

<div class="form-group" id="id_photo_group">
      <label >Photo*</label>
      <input type="file" class="dropify" data-height="300" id="id_member_photo" name="n_member_photo"/>
</div> 
</pre>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add input field as normal

*Html file*

```
 <input type="file"  name="n_service_img" id="id_service_image" />
```

From jquery file add class "dropify" and set its attributes and call dropify function

*jquery file*

```
      $("#id_service_image").addClass('dropify');
             $("#id_service_image").attr("data-height", 300);
             $("#id_service_image").attr("data-default-file", "../img/ourservices/MEDICAL-SERVICES.jpg");
             $('.dropify').dropify();
```

Comment: what if on document ready the dropify is already initialized ?

Comment: initialize when you put an image . when you are initializing with in document ready without image you can drop that statement and initialize when you dynamically adding image..

Comment: for those who are looking for load image with ajax call (or somehow they want to update image on dropify) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75844584/4671431

Answer (score 0):

Now can put default image using `data-default-file` variable

```
<input type="file" class="dropify" data-default-file="url_of_your_file" />
```

> **defaultFile**: If there is a default file on the input. You can use options when you use the plugin or directly
>   **data-default-file="url_of_your_file"** on you DOM element (it's recommended).

[Source](https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify/blob/master/README.md)