# How to set default image in dropify using jquery and ajax only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropify

I am using https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify  plugin for image upload and I am stuck at Edit page since I have to set default image but unable to do so.I have to do it using jquery and ajax. I have tried attr() and setting data-defalut-file() but no success. Also when i use data-defalut-file() i can see my image in inspect element but not on UI. Please help :)

I tried :

```
  $("#thumbnails_4_5").attr(
    "data-default-file",
    s3BaseUrlVideo +
      "/" +
      bucketName +
      "/" +
      images_folder +
      "/" +
      define_grid +
      "/" +
      horizontal +
      "/" +
      item.grid.thumbnail_4_5
  );
```

and

$('.dropify').dropify({
                       defaultFile: nameImage ,
                  });

Answer (score 4):

You cab use something like this(Using jQuery):

```
$('#input').attr("data-default-file", "imagePath");
$('#input').dropify():
```

Or you can set it directly

```
<input type="file" id="input" class="dropify" data-default-file="imagePath" />
```

Comment: I got  unexpected token: ':' in console and also i tried to replace it with ;.  but no success.

Comment: In my usecase i can't set it in html because it is dynamically attached. SO any other way to set in html using jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update dropify image by JS or JQuery code, you need to **remove** the element and then **append and initilize** it again!
something like this one :

```
                $('#imageInput , .dropify-wrapper').remove();
                
                html = `<input type="file" id="imageInput" class="dropify form-control" data-max-file-size="5M" id="imageInput" data-height="200" required=""
             data-default-file='your_url' />`;
                $('#imageInputContainer').append(html);
                $('#imageInput').dropify();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _newImageLink = '';
var drEvent = $('#file').dropify(
{
    defaultFile: _newImageLink
});
drEvent = drEvent.data('dropify');
drEvent.resetPreview();
drEvent.clearElement();
drEvent.settings.defaultFile = _newImageLink;
drEvent.destroy();
drEvent.init();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.