# How to set default image in dropify ? ( base64 image format )

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, dropify

I am using the https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify plugin for image upload and wish the `<input />` element show a thumbnail if there is already a file uploaded for the specified image.

I have found the [How to set default image in dropify using jquery and ajax only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106487/how-to-set-default-image-in-dropify-using-jquery-and-ajax-only) to work but as I am getting images that are saved in the database in base64 format from server this solution didn't solve my issue.

p.s. I am using .Net Core mvc and Javascript/jQuery

```
@if (Model.Product.RequiredImagesCount >= 1)
    {
        <form action="@($"/PrintOrder/OrderImageUpload?orderId={Model.Id}&imagePosition=0")" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <input type="file" name="File" class="dropify" data-max-file-size="50M" data-show-remove="false" data-default-file="" onchange="SubmitForm($(this));" />

            <div class="progress progress-striped d-none">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    }
```

Comment: Hi @SoroushBorhan, any updates about this case? If the answer did help achieve your requirement, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: for those who are looking for load image with ajax call (or somehow they want to update image on dropify) : stackoverflow.com/a/75844584/4671431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to set default image in dropify ? ( base64 image format )

To set default image in dropify using a base64 encoded image that is stored in your database, you can refer to the following approach.

```
<input type="file" name="File" class="dropify" data-max-file-size="50M" data-show-remove="false" data-default-file="" onchange="SubmitForm($(this));" />
```

*JS code*

```
$(function () {
    $('.dropify').dropify();

    resetPreview('File', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4RI....',
        'Image.jpg');
})

function resetPreview(name, src, fname = '') {
    let input = $('input[name="' + name + '"]');
    let wrapper = input.closest('.dropify-wrapper');
    let preview = wrapper.find('.dropify-preview');
    let filename = wrapper.find('.dropify-filename-inner');
    let render = wrapper.find('.dropify-render').html('');

    input.val('').attr('title', fname);
    wrapper.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-preview');
    filename.html(fname);

    render.append($('<img />').attr('src', src).css('max-height', input.data('height') || ''));
    preview.fadeIn();
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Same issue/requirement has been raised on [this github issue](https://github.com/JeremyFagis/dropify/issues/90#issuecomment-657687101) and above solution that @ruleboy21 shared works well for me.